# Azure AppService IIS does not have correct path to App

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio, azure-appservice

Trying to migrate a legacy ASP.NET WebForms/MVC hybrid application from Cloud Services to App Services. All runs fine locally in debug Visual Studio (V2022). The app is predominantly webforms but MVC has been retro fitted and is in use for some pages. It's using .NET Framework 4.8.

Deploying directly from Visual Studio. We have created a new App Service and App Service Plan. The site appears to deploy correctly but the endpoint returns the below as raw text, i.e. the web browser doesn't even attempt to render it, presumably as there is no header information specifying html content-type:

[image]

Have checked the configuration for the app service, all appears normal (same as other app services that run quite normally). It's set to ASP.NET 4.8 with all the other standard defaults. The default documents includes Default.aspx which matches the application. The application is using Forms authentication and defaults to a Login.aspx page. We have tried removing this and redeploying but we still get the same result. Configuration and Management diagnostics section on the Azure portal shows no significant errors.

[image]

In Kudu (advanced settings) if I access the debug console, I find my app is deployed to `c:\home\site\wwwroot>` as expected, however if I click "Site Root" it flips me to `c:\local>`

[image]

Could it be IIS is pointing to the wrong path for the site?

Comment: Just to be clear, the returned HTML sent as text is not from the application. I have no idea what is generating it, it bears no resemblance to any expected response. It doesn't look like the IIS default page either so has me somewhat baffled.

Answer (score 0):

In the end found some rogue code that was causing the issue. The different paths under Kudo was a red herring.

To diagnose the problem we moved from VS deployment to CI deployment and still had same issue. This meant it was not publishing settings. We compared web config with other solutions that ran fine as app services and found no significant differences. This ruled out IIS settings from web.server section. We checked for errors on the app and found no errors being reported.

In the end we trawled through the code and eventually found something that was URL specific.